# Shower panel - the swing arm doesn’t stay horizontal and sprays water from the top

Tags: shower, faucet

In the condo I bought, the bathrooms have identical shower panels. One works fine,  it in the other, the swinging arm doesn’t stay horizontal when lifted and also sprays water from the top.
The picture is of the working one.
Can it be repaired, or do I need to replace  it?[image]

Comment: Where does the spraying out the top occur? At the arm hinge points near the wall or out the top of the shower head itself?

Comment: Sounds like something is loose if the shower arm doesn't stay up....but please write more so we can help!